# Python Argparse - Что делать при вводе аргумента некорректного типа

Tags: python, python-3.x, консоль, argparse

Во время работы с модулем **argparse** в Python 3 встретился со странной проблемой.
Есть такой аргумент:

```
parser.add_argument('arg', metavar='arg', nargs='*', type=int)
```

Понятно, что он может принимать в себя любое значение **целых чисел**. Однако, в моем случае нужно сделать  корректную обработку тех случаев, когда вводится аргумент неправильного типа, например, **аргумент типа float**.
Я пытался "ловить" исключения при помощи try-except, однако, при парсинге аргумента неверного типа, программа сразу вылетает.

```
usage: useless.py [-h] [arg ...]
useless.py: error: argument arg: invalid int value: '5.0'
```

Comment: Убрать указание типа, обрабатывать аргумент как строку.

Comment: «второй вопрос» задайте, пожалуйста, отдельно.

Comment: В argparse нет встроенных методов для этого? Не хотелось бы говнокодить и изобретать велосипед :(

Comment: В версии argparse, которая идет с Python 3.9, можно указать чтобы программа принудительно не завершалась при ошибках: `argparse.ArgumentParser(exit_on_error=False)`, тогда можно будет отлавливать ошибки как исключения, см. [exit_on_error](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#exit-on-error). Но вообще не вижу ничего противоестественного в том, чтобы не указать тип, и обработать ошибки преобразования типа самостоятельно.

Comment: А пробовали в `try-except` ловить не `Exception`, а `SystemExit` или `BaseException`?

Comment: @CrazyElf а вот ловить BaseException - противоестественно)

Comment: @insolor Ну так то в целом да )